# Reuse instance of class

Tags: php, wordpress

I thinking I missing something out on OOP with PHP.

I am currently developing a plugin for WordPress where I have a class declaration for a book:

```
<?php
class WPBook{
    private $title;
    function setTitle($_title){
        $this->title = $_title;
    }
    function getTitle(){
        return $this->title;
    }
}
?>

add_action( 'hookOne', 'function_do_stuff');
add_action( 'hookAfter_hookOne', 'function_do_more_stuff');
function function_do_stuff(){

    //some more stuff
    $newBook = new WPBook;
    $title = $newBook->setTitle ='titleA';
    echo $title; //echos 'titleA';
    // function_do_more_stuff($title); does not work because the
    // function is called on the hookAfter_hookOne
}

function function_do_more_stuff(){
    // here I want to access the $title from the function_do_stuff();
    // but I do not know how.
}
```

Now I want to be able to access the title of the book from the `do_stuff()` function to function `do_more_stuff()`.

The problem however is that I can't use returns form `do_stuff()` to `do_more_stuff()`, because `do_more_stuff()` is called on a action-hook.

So my problem is that I do not know how to access the title of the same product from two different functions with passing one variable from one function to another function.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking, can you describe the problem a little bit better?

Comment: Can you give us sample code from the two functions you mentioned?

Comment: I added my example code, i hope you can understand it better now

Comment: You could persist the `$newBook` to the database and re-read it in `function_do_more_stuff`. Or does WordPress pass in an event object or similar into these hook handers? There might be an object you can store things in. Lastly you could declare the object as global, though that's rather inelegant.

Answer (score 0):

There is something obscure in this question, because your example uses custom hooks **hookOne** and **hookAfter_hookOne**.

This is important because, depending the way the hook is called, you will be able to use your class object as reference.

In case of basic call `<?php do_action('hookAfter_hookOne'); ?>` your stuck in the present case.

But if the hook is called with `<?php do_action_ref_array('hookAfter_hookOne', array(&$newbook)); ?>` [see doc. here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action_ref_array/) then you can access directly the referenced object like this:

```
<?php

function function_do_more_stuff(&$newbook){
   newbook->setTitle ='titleB';
}
```

Another way is to globalize the object outside of the functions, but it's maybe not the expected effect.

Hope it helps.